# Setting up ErpQueryEndpoint Destination for VDM

Tags: s4sdk, sap-cloud-platform

I have created a destination for VDM called ErpQueryEndpoint and have unsuccessfully attempted to obtain business partner info with one of the java VDM tutorials.  Below is an export of that destination - I've tried this with and without TrustAll = true.  When I use the 'Check Connection' button on the Destination screen, I get "302: Redirect" instead of 200.  When I attempt to navigate to the URL below from Chrome, it re-directs me to a non-SAP logon screen. (I believe our Basis team has tried to set-up SSO with Azure.)  I'm wondering if this redirection is what is causing my java VDM program to fail.

```
#Password=<< Existing password/certificate removed on export >>
#
#Mon Mar 11 15:17:38 UTC 2019
Description=ErpQueryEndPoint for java programs that use Virtual Data Model (VDM)
Type=HTTP
Authentication=BasicAuthentication
Name=ErpQueryEndpoint
ProxyType=Internet
URL=https\://my######-api.s4hana.ondemand.com
User=S000#######
```

Comment: Pls post the error message that you retrieve in the Java app log.
Are you sure that you have a technical (communication) user with your S-user?

Comment: I have a communication arrangement to obtain a list of sales contracts, and have created a Fiori app (which leveraged the Fiori List Report Element) which returns a list of sales contracts.  Here is the beginning part of what the Java app log shows:
servlet [com.cfindustries.s4sdk.SalesContractServlet] in context with path [/firstapp-application] threw exceptioncom.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.exception.ShouldNotHappenException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 20 path $

Comment: Can you pls post the entire stack trace (in the original message).

Apart from that, have you been able to invoke the Business Partner API (I understood you want to retrieve that) without your Java app, e.g. via Postman?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The tutorial program is now working. Getting a 302: Redirect when clicking 'Check Connection' was not the problem.  Even though only the base URL was in the destination, I still needed to supply the credentials from the business partner communication arrangement.  (It is also works for sales contracts when I supply the credentials from its respective communication arrangement.)

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved your issue. Could you pls post that as separate answer and mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. The tutorial program is now working. Getting a 302: Redirect when clicking 'Check Connection' was not the problem. Even though only the base URL was in the destination, I still needed to supply the credentials from the business partner communication arrangement. (It is also works for sales contracts when I supply the credentials from its respective communication arrangement.)